# Joining tables/records that might not exist sql

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT a.total
     , b.total
     , (a.total - b.total) as dv
     , a.customer_name
     , a.report_date
     , b.report_date 
  FROM topsourcesfcy a 
 CROSS 
  JOIN topsourcesfcy b 
 WHERE a.customer_name = b.customer_name 
   AND a.customer_name = 'SPECIALTY DRILLING FLUIDS LIMITED'
   AND a.report_date   = '2016-2-10' 
   AND b.report_date   = '2016-2-9' 
   AND a.report_date!  = b.report_date
```

but the problem is sometimes the record might exist in `a` and not in `b` or in `b` and not in `a`, which will cause the query to execute to false but I still want to select it if it exists in only one or both. 
Thanks.

Comment: See full outer joins in mysql.

Comment: @Strawberry mysql does not support full outer join, you need union to simulate it.

Comment: @Shadow I'm well aware of that thanks - as a simple search using those keywords would reveal.

Answer (score 0):

Read more thorough answers here:
[Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

What you want is a full outer join, but mysql doesn't support it.

Instead you can use a combo of two outer joins (left and right) and a union, the following will also remove dupes:

```
SELECT *
FROM `t1`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`

UNION

SELECT *
FROM `t1`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.`id` = `t2`.`id`
WHERE `t1`.`id` IS NULL;
```